# Please help me!

Tags: hvac, heating, thermostat, cooling

When setting my programmable thermostat should the 'heat to' or the 'cool to' setting be higher? Please ask me if you need any more info to answer this question

Comment: Bruce if want people to spend their time helping you, spend some time explaining the problem properly.

Answer (score 2):

In the interest of saving energy/money set the heat temperature as low as you can comfortably tolerate and set the cool high as you can tolerate.